# How should I arrange a test and production mirror of Ubuntu package repositories?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, mirrors, apt-mirror

I want to be able to closely standardise my Ubuntu 14.04 installations, there's a likelihood that the number of installations I have to complete will rise dramatically soon. I also want to be able to control updates on existing 14.04 systems. The systems in use support a range of different custom applications, and I need to make sure that updates do not alter the behaviour of these programs.

I want to put 3 mirrors in place on the same server; one 'live' mirror to download updates, a 'test' mirror, where I can keep a sort of snapshot of the repositories to update a test system, and check that there are no unwanted effects. Once I'm happy that functionality is intact, I would like to move these approved updates to a production mirror, on the same machine. This production mirror will be the source for updates of my production systems, and the source for new builds after using the normal installation medium (bootable USB).

I'm using `apt-mirror` and already have a working mirror of the Trusty repositories. I'm happy to keep this as up to date as possible, and know how to manage this. I understand how to use `apache` to make the various mirrors available over http, and how to alter the `/etc/apt/sources.list` files of the systems which will use the mirrors.

How can I efficiently manage these separate mirrors? I could copy the current state of the live mirror to the test mirror location, then on to the production mirror after approval, but this will use a lot of disk space. Is there a smarter way to do this? Would using some sort of union filesystem be the way to go?

Comment: Have you looked at `reprepro`?  https://mirrorer.alioth.debian.org/ it's a somewhat complex tool but seems to do what you want. I know you can add packages manually or move them from one repository to another.